# how to get user access token while using facebook connect with PHP SDK3.0

Tags: php, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hye,
i hav a situation. i m using php sdk3.0 for facebook connect and wanna signin users using there facebook id on my site. i m saving current user's detail to my db , how can i get users access token to user it later on.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<?php 
if ($_REQUEST['code']) {
    $app_id = "<app id>";
    $app_secret = "<secret key for your app>";
    $my_url = "<url to your app>";

    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&client_secret="
        . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

    $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

    $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?" . $access_token;

    $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

        echo $access_token . "<br />";
        echo $user->name . "<br />";
        echo $user->id . "<br />";
}
?>
```